# In vimrc, how can I chain multiple instructions in one Leader command

Tags: vimrc

In my .vimrc I have:

```
map <Leader>c :GitGutterToggle<CR>
map <Leader>n :set invnumber<CR>
```

Is there any way I can combine these two into one Leader entry?

For example:

```
map <Leader>c :GitGutterToggle && :set invnumber<CR>
```

I've tried the above, and variations thereof, to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that is `map <leader>c :execute 'GitGutterToggle \| set invnumber'<cr>`
I don't have gitgutter so I've tested it with `nnoremap <leader>c :exe 'echom "some" \| echom "other"'<cr>`

In fact it's even simpler than that.

```
nnoremap <leader>c :echo 'some' \| echo 'other'<cr>
```

Comment: Glad that I could help.